# When to use as.numeric and as.factor in R

Tags: r

I don't understand the difference between as.numeric and as.factor in R. When do I want to use each?

Example code:

```
data2$Response <- as.factor(data2$Response)
data2$VOT <- as.factor(data2$VOT)
data2$Block <- as.factor(data2$Block)
```

What will this do, exactly?

Answer (score 2):

Factors (with `as.factor`) are variables that have discrete values, which may or may not be ordered.  In other areas of science outside R they're often called categorical values.  For example North South East and West could be factors.

Numerics (with `as.numeric`) are numbers, with infinite other numbers between them.  So for example 5 is a number, as is 6, but so are 5.01, 5.001, 5.0001 etc.

To build a reproducible example similar to yours

```
data2 <- data.frame(numbers = c(1,2,3,4), text = c("one", "two", "three", "four"))
  numbers  text
1       1   one
2       2   two
3       3 three
4       4  four
```

I can use the numbers column to do math:

```
library(dplyr)
data2 %>%
mutate(square = numbers * numbers)
  numbers  text square
1       1   one      1
2       2   two      4
3       3 three      9
4       4  four     16
```

If I convert numbers to a factor, using `as.factor` though

```
data2$numbers <- as.factor(data2$numbers)
```

I'll no longer be able to do math (like squaring) using the values in `data2$numbers` because they're not numeric anymore.  They're factor levels named 1, 2, 3, 4, not the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4.  They could just as easily be named North South East and West, and West * West doesn't make any sense.

So to sum up, you'll want to use as.numeric when whatever you're passing are actually numbers, but perhaps coded as strings (`"1", "2", "3", "4"`) or something you'd like to represent as numbers (in the case of TRUE or FALSE values for example).  You'd like to use `as.factor` when you'd like to convert whatever you're passing to named categories, which may or may not have an order.

Does that answer your question?